# How to query database for an IP - Error

Tags: php, database, email, if-statement, ip

I am trying to make it so that if their IP is in the database then they can't send an email. In the php54_errors file it says

```
[30-Dec-2012 18:25:26 Europe/Dublin] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Submit.php on line 6
[30-Dec-2012 18:25:26 Europe/Dublin] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Submit.php on line 7
```

My PHP code is this

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("ip", $con);
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip='$ip'";
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "You have already registered!";
}
else { 
    echo"Your request has been sent!";
    $to = "admin@prisoneternity.org.uk";
    $subject = "Guard Application";
    $from = "guardapplication@prisoneternity.org.uk";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $message = "IGN = " . $_POST["Username"] . "</br>\n\nage = " . $_POST["age"] . "</br>\n\nreason = " . $_POST["reason"] . "</br>\n\nHow many times have they been guard = " . $_POST["guard"] . "</br>\n\nOther Details = " . $_POST["text"];
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    header ("Location: index.php?email=yes");
    session_start();
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip (IP) VALUES ('$ip')");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second line, `mysql_num_rows` is returning an **integer** because the `$result` variable is already calling the function, if that makes sense. Change it to this:

```
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($result > 0) {
```

Also, you're not running the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip='$ip'";
```

Change the above line to this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip='$ip'");
```

On a side note, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. I'd switch to `PDO` or `MySQLi` — examples can be found in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual).

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

should be:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

You were not running the `mysql_query()`, instead calling `mysql_num_rows()` twice. Simple accident =o) Btw you should be using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Also:

```
echo"Your request has been sent!";
$to = "admin@prisoneternity.org.uk";
$subject = "Guard Application";
$from = "guardapplication@prisoneternity.org.uk";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$message = "IGN = " . $_POST["Username"] . "</br>\n\nage = " . $_POST["age"] . "</br>\n\nreason = " . $_POST["reason"] . "</br>\n\nHow many times have they been guard = " . $_POST["guard"] . "</br>\n\nOther Details = " . $_POST["text"];
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header ("Location: index.php?email=yes");
session_start();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip (IP) VALUES ('$ip')");
```

Should be:

```
$to = "admin@prisoneternity.org.uk";
$subject = "Guard Application";
$from = "guardapplication@prisoneternity.org.uk";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$message = "IGN = " . $_POST["Username"] . "</br>\n\nage = " . $_POST["age"] . "</br>\n\nreason = " . $_POST["reason"] . "</br>\n\nHow many times have they been guard = " . $_POST["guard"] . "</br>\n\nOther Details = " . $_POST["text"];
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
//header ("Location: index.php?email=yes");
session_start();
echo"Your request has been sent!";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip (IP) VALUES ('$ip')");
```

You can not echo content before `header()` or `session_start()`, also the echoed text will not be seen as you are doing a redirect. You need to choose which one you want to do. I commented out the `header()` above but you can do the opposite. Also make sure you sanitize ALL `$_POST` values for `\r` and `\n` characters to prevent [mail header injection attacks](http://phpsense.com/2006/php-email-injection-attacks/).